# Android gesture detection and recognition

Tags: android, view, gesture-recognition, gesturedetector, swipe-gesture

I'm trying to add "fling" gesture detection in simple gesture recognition source code that developer has([on this site](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/gestures-on-android-16.html)). and this is the code:

```
public class GestureMix extends Activity implements OnGesturePerformedListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private GestureLibrary mLibrary;
private static final int LARGE_MOVE= 60;
private static final String TAG= "Debug";
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

TextView tv;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    gestureDetector= new GestureDetector(this, new SimpleOnGestureListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY){
            if(e1.getY()- e2.getY() > LARGE_MOVE){
                tv.setText("\nFling Ke Atas dengan kecepatan" +velocityY);
                //tv.append("\nFling Ke Atas dengan kecepatan" +velocityY);
                Log.d(TAG, "\nFling Ke Atas dengan kecepatan" +velocityY);
                return true;
            } else if(e2.getY()-e1.getY() > LARGE_MOVE){
                tv.setText("\nFling Ke Bawah dengan kecepatan" +velocityY);
                //tv.append("\nFling Ke Bawah dengan kecepatan" +velocityY);
                Log.d(TAG,"\nFling Ke Bawah dengan kecepatan" +velocityY );
                return true;
            } else if(e1.getX()-e2.getX() > LARGE_MOVE){
                tv.setText("\nFling Ke Kiri dengan kecepatan" +velocityX);
                //tv.append("\nFling Ke Kiri dengan kecepatan" +velocityX);
                Log.d(TAG, "\nFling Ke Kiri dengan kecepatan" +velocityX);
                return true;
            } else if(e2.getX()-e1.getX() > LARGE_MOVE){
                tv.setText("\nFling Ke Kanan dengan kecepatan" +velocityX);
                //tv.append("\nFling Ke Kanan dengan kecepatan" +velocityX);
                Log.d(TAG,"\nFling Ke Kanan dengan kecepatan" +velocityX );
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    Log.d(TAG, "d on create");

     mLibrary= GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
    if(!mLibrary.load()){
        finish();
    }

    GestureOverlayView gst= (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gesture);
    gst.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG, "d gesture perform");
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions= mLibrary.recognize(gesture);

    if(predictions.size()>0){
        Prediction prediction= predictions.get(0);

        if(prediction.score >1.0){
            Toast.makeText(this, prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, prediction.name);
        }
    }   
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    Log.d(TAG, "d on touch");
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

}

The gesture recognition went well (it toast the right result), but the gesture detection (onfling) won't show the result (it won't appear whether in the textview or in the logCat. It seems the gesture detector won't work on **gestureoverlayview**.

How could I fix this code, so I could see the gesture recognition and the velocity of the fling as the result?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Please ask for clarification and I'll happily tell you the specifics of what I've tried.

I'm sorry for my bad in English and less knowledge in programming. Thanks.

Comment: hey your "ON THIS SITE" is going to error page can you able to correct it

Comment: @Sreekanthss : Hey, here I fix my "on this site" links, thank's. Hope you'll solved it.